# Can you remove the xAxes border line and keep the ticks only?

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

I am trying to remove the border of the Chart without removing the labels ticks

I have searched for settings to do this however found none as the 'Display: false' will hide everything.

The chart I am using can be seen here:
https://codepen.io/paufar/pen/VOpZGQ

```
options: {
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          display: false
        }], 
      xAxes:  [{
          gridLines: {
          display:false
          }
      }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using:

`gridLines: { drawBorder: false }`